# How do I install psycopg2 on Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, psycopg2

I'm trying to install psycopg2 on anaconda spyder. 
I went to anaconda cloud and tried what they specified:

conda install -c anaconda psycopg2

However, I get the error:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: are you in anaconda prompt ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run this command on bash and not on python console!

If u want to run it on python console then try this

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("conda install -c anaconda psycopg2", shell=True)
```